# Find count of digits in string variable

Tags: java

I have a string which sometimes gives character value and sometimes gives integer value. I want to get the count of number of digits in that string.

For example, if string contains "2485083572085748" then total number of digits is 16.

Please help me with this.

Comment: for example if string contains "2485083572085748" then total number of integers is 1.

Comment: @Andrey, it seems he means to say 'digits' instead of 'integers'. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Vikram I understand, that what I wanted to point out.

Comment: @Andrey, Ok. Got it! :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
String s = "2485083572085748";
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0, len = s.length(); i < len; i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to avoid `toCharArray` on purpose because it is a bit slower according to my test. Also, calculating the length only once should be a little bit faster. The `Character.isDigit` may not be optimal however; possibly `c >= '0' && c <= '9'` is faster.

Answer (score 27):

A cleaner solution using Regular Expressions:

```
// matches all non-digits, replaces it with "" and returns the length.
s.replaceAll("\\D", "").length()
```

Comment: I doubt evaluating a regexp for all characters would be faster than counting them. But I like the conciseness so have my upvote.

Answer (score 7):

Just to refresh this thread with stream option of counting digits in a string:

```
"2485083572085748".chars()
                  .filter(Character::isDigit)
                  .count();
```

Answer (score 3):

If your string gets to big and full of other stuff than digits you should try to do it with regular expressions. Code below would do that to you:

```
String str = "asdasd 01829898 dasds ds8898";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\d"); // "\d" is for digits in regex
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
int count = 0;
while(m.find()){
   count++;
}
```

check out [java regex lessons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) for more.
cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Loop each character and count it.

```
    String s = "2485083572085748";
    int counter = 0;
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if( c >= '0' && c<= '9') {
            ++counter;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int getCount(String number) {
    int flag = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(number.charAt(i))) {
            flag++;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in JavaScript:

```
str = "2485083572085748"; //using the string in the question
let nondigits = /\D/g;  //regex for all non-digits
let digitCount = str.replaceAll(nondigits, "").length;
//counts the digits after removing all non-digits
console.log(digitCount); //see in console
```

Thanks --> https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396264/vedant for the Java version above. It helped me too.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
for(char c: str.toCharArray()) {
    if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

**Also see**

- [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29)

Answer (score -3):

Something like:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


            Regex r = new Regex( "[0-9]" );
            Console.WriteLine( "Matches " + r.Matches("if string contains 2485083572085748 then" ).Count );
```