# Word has exact X letters and Y digits

Tags: regex

I need to check whether a word has exactly 6 letters and 1 digit or not.
I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33965251/6063416) and modified my regex to look like this:

`^[a-zA-Z]{6}\d{1}$`  (meaning any letter between a-z or A-Z 6 times and  1 digit)

but I get no matches for any string that I could imagine (examples: sixsix1, 1sixsix, six1six)
I am using [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to compile the regex

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `A-Z` in the second range (inside the character class)? After fixing that, your regex should be fine.

Comment: Yes. I modified.

Comment: If you want to match the digit *anywhere* in the string, I don't think regex is your best tool. What language are you using?

Comment: this should match sixsix1 but not 1sixsix because your regex is looking for 6 letters *followed* by a digit.

Comment: I am using Java.

Comment: @SnuKies You'd better write a counting function instead of trying to solve with RegEx.

Comment: @SnuKies Then count how many digits and characters are there.. Regex is not a good option.

Comment: [Now you have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Comment: Ok. I'll do write my own function, then. Thank you, guys! You saved me some time

Comment: `"^(?=\\D*\\d\\D*$)(?=(?:\\P{L}*\\p{L}){6}\\P{L}*$)\\p{Alnum}{7}$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's scary.

Comment: @MarounMaroun That depends, I find it very gentle :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Literally became nauseous upon seeing that. Surely you don't recommend that as a solution :)

Comment: I think a regex is the wrong tool for this problem. Just loop over the string and count the letters and numebrs

Comment: How about matching for a letter against the string, then getting the array length? If it is 6, match for a digit. If the second array length is one, you’re there. No serious reflex.

Comment: @Rotem It all depends on the real situation. When one has no access to real code, the regex comes to the rescue. Here, OP says they have access to code, so there is no need to suggest it as a solution. It might be of help to others though.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
^(?=^[^\d]*\d{1}[^\d]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/POns84/3)

Explanation:

1. `(?=^[^\d]*\d{1}[^\d]*$)` ensures to look for just a single number
   in the entire string.
2. `[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}` ensures there is 7 character within a-zA-Z0-9. As
   previously it was confirmed that there is no more than 1 number thus
   it will only match when it has 6 chars and one number.

Comment: When the regex is ugly, that's a sign you shouldn't use it. Also it's not correct, since it matches also two digits: "six13si" (and more).

Comment: This also matches more than one digit, e.g. `1111six`

Comment: Well I figure that out ! But I wasn't shouting. While communicating via text , when the sentence is written  in full capital are called SHOUTING. I wasn't shouting. Anyway thanks for figuring that out. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Nice one, could probably even [make it a bit shorter](https://regex101.com/r/POns84/4)

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5564375/860585) answer since I've never written Java:

```
String s = "six1six";
if (s.length() != 7) return false;
int digits = 0;
int letters = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
        digits++;
    }
    else if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) {
        letters++;
    }
}
return digits == 1 && letters == 6;
```

Is there really no LINQ equivalent in Java? this is hideous.